# Comparing reputation graph of two or more users

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-graph

In network profile of a user there's a reputation tab, which shows a graph for reputation over time of that user for all sites (for 200+ rep).

What should I do if I want to compare someone's graph with mine, in a single graph? Also the question can be applied to more than two users!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ChrisF To compare in which months I had more activity and in which he has more! Anyway we could ask, why someone would want to see other people's reputation graph at all? So why is it public?

Comment: You have the reputation leagues for that, though it's per-site. To have what you want you need to write your own code, users reputation is public and also exposed via [API](http://stackapps.com/).

Comment: If you have a good reason - and include it in the question - then your request is more likely to be considered.

Comment: Do it in Excel. Record all the reputation changes for all the days of interest for yourself and whoever else. Put them in Excel, and use a bar chart. :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Rep Compare - Utility for Comparing Reputation - Version 0.8](https://stackapps.com/q/1471/9) to graph your reputation on the same scale as other users.  It's an app that you have to download and run, but the guy who wrote it is pretty trustworthy (he's a Stack Overflow moderator).